# Why not pasting image url automatically if we choose it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are two options on inserting image:

- Browse
- paste

[image]

Why not pasting image url automatically if we choose `paste` option?

Comment: if you have an image in the clipboard you don't need to use that dialog at all, you can simply paste into the edit box on the main page.

Comment: What if i have just its url?

Comment: then you need the upload dialog. Either way any kind of site mechanism updates would always be network wide not specific to tex.sx so you probably should raise on the main meta rather than here.

Answer (score 6):

That can't be done due to privacy concerns: Since the pasteboard may contain sensitive data, javascript in a web page is not allowed read access. There is ongoing work allowing this in very limited contexts, though. For example, see [Async Clipboard API](https://webkit.org/blog/10855/) (WebKit); especially, the headline “Security and Privacy”. But if you have to respond to a privacy related popup, it seems not much is gained over just doing the paste yourself.